Verb conjugation in 'Edit Summary'
Quand je fais des modifications sur le Wikipédia ou StackExchange, quel temps de verbe utiliser dans mes sommaires des modifications (e.g, 'ajout un lien' et 'modifie le paragraphe')? Indicatif présent ? Impératif présent ? Ou autrement ?


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

La présence d'un verbe n'est pas obligatoire dans la description d'une action. Le plus courant est d'utiliser le substantif qui correspond à l'action, ex. :

Ajout d'un lien.
Modification du deuxième paragraphe.
Correction du code.
Suppression d'un paragraphe hors sujet.
Amélioration de la mise en page.

ou alors, un participe passé :

Lien ajouté.
Deuxième paragraphe modifié.
Code corrigé.
…


Ou un p. pass. non conjugué: Ajouté un lien, Corrigé le code, etc.

@FrançoisJurain Oui, c'est courant aussi : Réponse modifiée ;-)
